# Qt static linked call gstreamer functions

Tags: c++, qt, static, gstreamer

I write a library (a plugin) for another application with Qt. In this library I use gstreamer to decode audio/video data. Until today I used dynamic linked Qt. Now I tried to link Qt static (compiled, add in Qt-Creator, made and use new kit). Compiling worked fine but gstreamer does nothing. I did not changed anything in the project file. I get no error, no output, nothing. When I set a breakpoint (e.g. at `g_object_set()` or `gst_element_set_state()`) the debugger stops at the right place but nothing happens.

Do I need to configure Qt special for static compiling or something?

My setup: Debian 8, Qt 5.5.1, gstreamer 1.0
Configure options for Qt: `-static- no-use-gold-linker -no-gstreamer -qt-xcb -nomake examples`

Comment: Are you on a *nix platform by any chance? Because if you linked statically to Qt Multimedia, that includes its own copy of GStreamer. If that's the case it's probably a linking issue.

Comment: I use debian. I tryed to compile Qt with -no-gstreamer but same effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a QThread you need to initiate a QCoreApplication. Without this QEventLoop will not run.